# How to save fetched objects to core data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm very new to programming in general and objective c core data in particular. I am trying to read data from a spreadsheet and display it in a tableview. The array I created to hold the objects is empty. I am unsure how to save the data to the array. Plus I'm getting a warning that the value stored is never read. I would GREATLY appreciate any assistance on this--at my wit's end.

Here's my code:

```
DataStorage *parentTab;
parentTab = (DataStorage *)self.parentViewController;
_context = [parentTab context];

[self populateCollegeObjects];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *dataEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CollegeList"     inManagedObjectContext:_context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:dataEntity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"collegeName" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors ];
[sortDescriptors release];
[sortDescriptor release];

NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
[fetchRequest release];

NSError *error;
[controller performFetch:&error];

for (int counter = 0; counter< [sortDescriptors count]; counter ++)
{
   if ([_collegeObjects count] == 0)
    {
        _collegeObjects = [[NSArray alloc] init];

        CollegeList *addCollege;

        //addCollege = [CollegeList initWithName:<#(NSString *)#> andURL:<#(NSString *)#> andDetail:<#(NSString *)#> forContext:<#(NSManagedObjectContext *)#>_context];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the sortDescriptors and fetchRequest release statements should be after the performFetch method.

Comment: Sorry I don't get one thing - you fetch data in NSFetchedReultsController and then save that data (using initWithName)?

Comment: What are you asking exactly? You want to read data from spreadsheet and put them in tableview, and then you have an array that is empty? Where did this array come from? In your question you did not mention core data once. Where do you need core data on this one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure exactly what your question is. Is the array suppose to be filled with entities from your core data?

Maybe you can try this to see if this helps:

```
[fetchRequest setEntity:dataEntity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [_context executeFetchRequest: fetchRequest error: nil];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"collegeName" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedFetchedObjects = [fetchedObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

The sortedFetchedObjects should contain an array of the sorted objects you are looking for.

Comment: I tried the code you suggested, as well as moved the release statements to after the perform fetch method recommended by @user427969. Neither worked--the array is still empty.